# Filter Dynamo DB rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to filter all dynamo db rows where 2 columns have same value

```
 table = client.Table('XXX')
   response = table.query(
   KeyConditionExpression=Key('column1').eq(KeyConditionExpression=Key('column2'))
 )
```

this is wrong as we can't pass KeyConditionExpression inside eq statement. I don't want to scan through all the rows and filter the rows.

Scanned through multipole resources and answers but every resources talks about the multiple column checking with some value not multiple condition involving columns

Is there anyway we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

If you want query over all records you need to use `scan`, if you want to query only records with one specific partition key you can use `query`.

For both you can use a [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression), which will filter the records after retrieving them from the database, but before returning them to the user (so beware, using a scan with this will read **all** your records).

A scan from the CLI could look like this:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name your-table \
    --filter-expression "#i = #j" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#i": "column1", "#j": "column2"}'
```

Comment: i am able to get it working with scan like this response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('col1').eq(Attr('col2'))
    ) , but i dont want to use scan, is it possible with query

Comment: Scan is a costly operation , so was wondering can it be achieved with query

Comment: Query only searches within a specific partition and requires a partition key for that. So if you want to retrieve records from the whole table you will not be able to use Query.

Comment: got it, i thought there can be some ways to optimise it, Filterexpression works in same for java as well ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
    .withTableName("XXX")
    .withFilterExpression("Col1 = Col2l") ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global Secondary Index with a partition key of 'Column1Value#Column2Value'

Then it's simply a matter of querying the GSI.